# Custom plugins in a Chromium-like browser in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, chromium

I still use the (really) old Pocket Chrome extension
that downloads the articles on my desktop (Arch Linux). 
My main browser is Chromium (which can be installed easily on Arch Linux).

On new devices this extension had to be installed manually. 
I kept a copy of it; this worked fine.

However, as of December 2022, the Linux version of Chromium
(getting in line with Windows and Mac) disabled any extensions installed this way.

This is not a matter of Chromium v. Chrome:

- Chrome has the same issue of not allowing non-store extensions. 
  See [Chrome Extensions Manifest V2 support timeline - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/).
- Also, Chrome is not easily installable on Arch.

How can I still run a Chrome/Chromium-like browser
that supports extensions (that are not from the Google store)
now that Chrome and Chromium no longer allow this?

Comment: Why don't you install Chrome?

Comment: Because it's not easily installable on Arch. I get it.

Comment: It is not easily installable on Arch, but also Chrome on Linux doesn't allow non-store extensions anymore either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Brave (chromium-based) browser still allows for the installation of unpacked extensions.

It shows a warning that it will stop working in December 2022, but as of January 2023 it is still working if you click "open anyway".

This works for me for now.

[image: brave extensions]

EDIT: screenshots of the result (with 11 Jan 2023 in the title)

[image]

Comment: as a sidenote, first time I looked at Brave, but it's pretty decent. might be worth the AUR install. it has a "hide cooking popups" feature